# Match multiple combinations of two columns

Tags: mariadb

I have this sample dataset of product reviews. I'm trying to get users who rated certain products positively. Ratings are numbers 1-5, 5 being the best and 1 being the worst.

[image: dataset]

I tried the following queries:

```
SELECT user, product, rating FROM reviews WHERE user != 1 (product = 173 AND rating > 3) AND (product = 50 AND rating > 3);
SELECT user FROM reviews WHERE user != 1 GROUP BY user HAVING (product = 173 AND rating > 3) AND (product = 50 AND rating > 3);
SELECT user, product, rating FROM reviews WHERE user != 1 AND (product, rating) IN ((173, 4), (50, 4))
```

None of them work. I'm looking for users who rated product 173, 4 or 5 AND rated product 50, 4 or 5. Its easy to get results where one of the combinations match but I need to match all conditions of product, rating combinations.

I prepared a fiddle: [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gGmLCpQMkDoeFQC5TZ8YKM/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are using MySQL, we could try the following aggregation approach with tuple syntax:

```sql
SELECT user
FROM reviews
WHERE (product, rating) IN ((173, 4), (173, 5), (50, 4), (50, 5)) AND user <> 1
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product) = 2;
```

The `WHERE` clause of this query restricts to only records rating products 173 and 50 with ratings of 4 or 5.  It then aggregates by user and asserts in the `HAVING` clause that *both* products were rated as 4 or 5.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm getting the right results but don't understand it. If you have time, could you explain how it works?

Comment: @Whip I have added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. If there are 3 products then I use `COUNT(DISTINT product) = 3`, right?

Comment: Yes, that might be correct, depending on the question.